# Getting all result with search using cake php

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

If I want to search for all results , which the search link is such as that :

http://192.168.1.91/UQUV2/uqu_system/sterilization/sterilization-task-orders/result?sterilization_status_id=&users_id=&sterilization_types_id=&sterilization_tasks_id=&sterilization_task_types_id=

And I'm using this code to do that :

```
$query = $this->SterilizationTaskOrders
            ->find()
            ->Where([
    'SterilizationTaskOrders.sterilization_types_id IS' => '',
    'SterilizationTaskOrders.sterilization_task_types_id IS' => NULL,
    'SterilizationTaskOrders.sterilization_status_id IS' => NULL,
    'SterilizationTaskOrders.users_id IS' => NULL,
    'SterilizationTaskOrders.sterilization_tasks_id IS' => NULL 
])
```

But it's getting me null and not getting me with the all results !

what's wrong with that code please?

Comment: why you use `Where` instead `where` ?

Comment: It doesn't make different with the result .

Comment: Why are you using a blank string for sterilization_types_id instead of null? Also, you're aware that this query will find all orders where *all* of these conditions are true? Seems to me that, to find all results, you want to have *no* conditions on the find.